# python - sklearn 0.17 and 0.18 - how to retrieve only the first value of an StratifiedKFold object?

Tags: python, scikit-learn

I have a python problem.
I use scikit-learn 0.17
Someone give me an example code that I have to run.
The code was in python 2, and scikit-learn 0.18, the dev version.
I transformed the code in python 3 without issue.
But he used the function :

```
sklearn.model_selection.StratifiedKFold(n_folds=3, shuffle=False, random_state=None)
```

In scikit-learn 0.17, I have function that looks like this one :

```
sklearn.cross_validation.StratifiedKFold(y, n_folds=3, shuffle=False, random_state=None)
```

As you can see, they seem very similar : there is only the "y" that change.

So I have two solution : update to 0.18 (I'm using windows, and I can't use linux) I tried this one, but I don't succeed to compile sources.

The second solution is to use the StratifiedKFold of 0.17.
I succeed this solution. (I don't know if it doing the things it suppose to do, however x) ).

So, there is my problem (finally) :

I have to adapt this two line :

```
skf = StratifiedKFold(n_folds=5)
train_idx, test_idx = skf.split(patch_arr, labels).next()
```

for the moment, I wrote this (cover your eyes):

```
skf = StratifiedKFold(labels, n_folds=5)
for train_idx, test_idx in skf:
    break
```

And the program run, but my code is awful. Is there any other method to retrieve only the first couple of (train_idx, test_idx) ?
I tried with skf[0] and skf.next(), but none of this works.

(for your information, train_idx and test_idx are two arrays)

Have you got any idea ?
I find strange that I can't use patch_arr in my solution too, but if I can avoid to spend more hours trying to update scikit-image, I will be very happy :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following should suffice.

```
train_idx, test_idx = next(iter(skf))
```